# Ethernet icon in panel although I am using WiFi

Tags: wireless, network-manager, ethernet

I have the Ethernet icon active when I'm already using Wifi, what's happening?

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: I have been looking for a permanent fix since I started using Ubuntu but haven't found one.

Answer (score 0):

It's a bug that hasn't been fixed...

run this command and it will correct it.  Or just let it be since it still works.

```
  sudo systemctl restart network-manager.service
```